# Reading outlook mail in Javamail API - AUTHENTICATE failed error message

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail

I'm currently doing a requirement related of fetching the specific Email ID content from outlook "inbox" via javaMail API . In stackoverflow, i came across one previous solution found  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285378/how-to-read-email-of-outlook-with-javamail). When running the above solved code , ot is still throwing a `AUTHENTICATE failed` error message

NOTE : I have configured my outlook in Microsoft Exchange Server

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.3
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG: trying to connect to host "imap-mail.outlook.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [UwBHADIAUABSADAAMQBDAEEAMAAwADkANAAuAGEAcABjAHAAcgBkADAAMQAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBlAHgAYwBoAGEAbgBnAGUAbABhAGIAcwAuAGMAbwBtAA==]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: PLAIN
IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=imap-mail.outlook.com, user=myemailid.domain.com, password=<non-null>
A1 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
+ 
a3VtYXJzLnBAaGNsLmNvbQBrdW1hcnMucEBoY2wuY29tAFBhc3N3b3JkQDEyMDQ=
A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
Exception while connecting to server: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

`

Comment: Hey there! Welcome to Stack overflow! checkout this guide on how to ask good questions on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  Setting the property `mail.debug.auth` to true will give you more details that might help, but don't post that output here because it will contain your password.

Comment: Bill Shannon..debug output is enabled and trace stopped at below step:
A1 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
+ 
a3VtYXJzLnBAaGNsLmNvbQBrdW1hcnMucEBoY2wuY29tAFBhc3N3b3JkQDEyMDQ=
A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.

Answer (score 0):

Bill Shannon..Debug output is enabled and trace stopped at below step:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.3
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG: trying to connect to host "imap-mail.outlook.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [UwBHADIAUABSADAAMQBDAEEAMAAwADkANAAuAGEAcABjAHAAcgBkADAAMQAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBlAHgAYwBoAGEAbgBnAGUAbABhAGIAcwAuAGMAbwBtAA==]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: PLAIN
IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=imap-mail.outlook.com, user=myemailid.domain.com, password=<non-null>
A1 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
+ 
a3VtYXJzLnBAaGNsLmNvbQBrdW1hcnMucEBoY2wuY29tAFBhc3N3b3JkQDEyMDQ=
A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
Exception while connecting to server: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```